# Misbehavior when trying to store a string set using SharedPreferences

Tags: android, android-preferences

I'm trying to store a set of strings using the [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) API.

```
Set<String> stringSet = sharedPrefs.getStringSet("key", new HashSet<String>());
stringSet.add(new_element);

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
editor.putStringSet(stringSet);
editor.commit()
```

The first time I execute the code above, `stringSet` is set to the default value (the just created and empty `HashSet`) and it is stored without problems.

The second and subsequent times I execute this code, a `stringSet` object is returned with the first element added. I can add the element and, during the program execution, it is apparently stored in the `SharedPreferences`. However, when the program is killed and the `SharedPreferences` is loaded again from persistent storage, the newer values are lost.

How can the second and subsequent elements be stored so that they don't get lost?

Comment: shouldn't the code be calling editor.putStringSet()?

Comment: @bluehallu super old comment but I fixed that line since it seems the OP has abandoned it.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

This "problem" is documented on [`SharedPreferences.getStringSet`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getStringSet%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29).

The `SharedPreferences.getStringSet` returns a reference of the stored HashSet object 
inside the `SharedPreferences`. When you add elements to this object, they are added in fact inside the `SharedPreferences`.

That is ok, but the problem comes when you try to store it: Android compares the modified HashSet that you are trying to save using `SharedPreferences.Editor.putStringSet` with the current one stored on the `SharedPreference`, and both are the same object!!!

A possible solution is to make a copy of the `Set<String>` returned by the `SharedPreferences` object:

```
Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>(sharedPrefs.getStringSet("key", new HashSet<String>()));
```

That makes `s` a different object, and the strings added to `s` will not be added to the set stored inside the `SharedPreferences`.

Other workaround that will work is to use the same `SharedPreferences.Editor` transaction to store another simpler preference (like an integer or boolean), the only thing you need is to force that the stored value are different on each transaction (for example, you could store the string set size).

Comment: I already +1 but could you please provide a link to the source backing up your claim that : "Android compares the modified HashSet that you are trying to save using SharedPreferences.Editor.putStringSet with the current one stored on the SharedPreference"

Comment: The second option (save a counter) worked fine for me. Thanks!

Comment: Spent 9 hours staring at my code on this one. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D and anyone interested I've added a source code explanation answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56553439/708906

Answer (score 13):

This behaviour is documented so it is by design:

from getStringSet:

> "Note that you must not modify the set instance returned by this call. The consistency of the stored data is not guaranteed if you do, nor is your ability to modify the instance at all."

And it seems quite reasonable especially if it is documented in the API, otherwise this API would have to make copy on each access. So the reason for this design was probably performance. I suppose they should make this function return result wrapped in unmodifiable class instance, but this once again requires allocation.

Comment: I edited my own answer this afternoon. I realized that it is properly documented, but when you are writing code many times you don't look to the documentation in things like that. This is the only reason to keep this ask+answer, IMHO, because it is a utility class and this kind of explanation can help anyone. Thanks for your clarification too

Answer (score 7):

Was searching for a solution for the same issue, resolved it by:

1) Retrieve the existing set from the shared preferences

2) Make a copy of it

3) Update the copy

4) Save the copy

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
Set<String> oldSet = sharedPrefs.getStringSet("key", new HashSet<String>());

//make a copy, update it and save it
Set<String> newStrSet = new HashSet<String>();    
newStrSet.add(new_element);
newStrSet.addAll(oldSet);

editor.putStringSet("key",newStrSet); edit.commit();
```

[Why](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getStringSet(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E))

Answer (score 6):

### Source Code Explanation

While the other good answers on here have correctly pointed out that this potential issue is documented in [SharedPreferences.getStringSet()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences?hl=en#getStringSet(java.lang.String,%2520java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)), basically "Don't modify the returned Set because the behavior isn't guaranteed", I'd like to actually contribute the source code that causes this problem/behavior for anyone that wants to dive deeper.

Taking a look at [SharedPreferencesImpl](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/core/java/android/app/SharedPreferencesImpl.java) (source code as of Android Pie) we can see that in `SharedPreferencesImpl.commitToMemory()` there is a comparison that occurs between the original value (a `Set<String>` in our case) and the newly modified value:

```
private MemoryCommitResult commitToMemory() {
    // ... other code

    // mModified is a Map of all the key/values added through the various put*() methods.
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> e : mModified.entrySet()) {
        String k = e.getKey();
        Object v = e.getValue();
        // ... other code

        // mapToWriteToDisk is a copy of the in-memory Map of our SharedPreference file's
        // key/value pairs.
        if (mapToWriteToDisk.containsKey(k)) {
            Object existingValue = mapToWriteToDisk.get(k);
            if (existingValue != null && existingValue.equals(v)) {
                continue;
            }
        }
        mapToWriteToDisk.put(k, v);
    }
```

So basically what's happening here is that when you try to write your changes to file this code will loop through your modified/added key/value pairs and check if they already exist, and will only write them to file if they don't or are different from the existing value that was read into memory.

The key line to pay attention to here is `if (existingValue != null && existingValue.equals(v))`. You're new value will only be written to disk if `existingValue` is `null` (doesn't already exist) or if `existingValue`'s contents are different from the new value's contents.

**This the the crux of the issue.** `existingValue` is read from memory. The SharedPreferences file that you are trying to modify is read into memory and stored as `Map<String, Object> mMap;` (later copied into `mapToWriteToDisk` each time you try to write to file). When you call `getStringSet()` you get back a `Set` from this in-memory Map. If you then add a value to this same `Set` instance, you are modifying the **in-memory** Map. Then when you call `editor.putStringSet()` and try to commit, `commitToMemory()` gets executed, and the comparison line tries to compare your newly modified value, `v`, to `existingValue` which is basically the same in-memory `Set` as the one you've just modified. The object instances are different, because the `Set`s have been copied in various places, but the contents are identical.

**So** you're trying to compare your new data to your old data, but you've already unintentionally updated your old data by directly modifying that `Set` instance. Thus your new data will not be written to file.

#### But why are the values stored initially but disappear after the app is killed?

As the OP stated, it seems as if the values are stored while you're testing the app, but then the new values disappear after you kill the app process and restart it. This is because while the app is running and you're adding values, you're **still** adding the values to the in-memory `Set` structure, and when you call `getStringSet()` you're getting back this same in-memory `Set`. All your values are there and it looks like it's working. But after you kill the app, this in-memory structure is destroyed along with all the new values since they were never written to file.

### Solution

As others have stated, just avoid modifying the in-memory structure, because you're basically causing a side-effect. So when you call `getStringSet()` and want to reuse the contents as a starting point, just copy the contents into a different `Set` instance instead of directly modifying it: `new HashSet<>(getPrefs().getStringSet())`. Now when the comparison happens, the in-memory `existingValue` will actually be different from your modified value `v`.

Comment: Basically it won't work because Set is a reference type and the implementation of SharedPreferences only compares the reference not the content. The reference won't change if you change the content.

Answer (score 2):

I tried all the above answers none worked for me.
So I did the following steps

1. before adding new element to the list of old shared pref, make a copy of it
2. call a method with the above copy as a param to that method.
3. inside that method clear the shared pref which are holding that values.
4. add the values present in copy to the cleared shared preference it will treat it as new.

   ```
   public static void addCalcsToSharedPrefSet(Context ctx,Set<String> favoriteCalcList) {

   ctx.getSharedPreferences(FAV_PREFERENCES, 0).edit().clear().commit();

   SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = ctx.getSharedPreferences(FAV_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
   editor.putStringSet(FAV_CALC_NAME, favoriteCalcList);
   editor.apply(); }
   ```

I was facing issue with the values not being persistent, if i reopen the app after cleaning the app from background only first element added to the list was shown.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a note, Shared Preferences can't just be overwritten.
If you have assigned a value to it, you have to remove it first by the method `remove(KEY)` and then `commit()` to destroy the key.
Then you can assign a new value to it.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getStringSet(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)