# SharedPreferences putStringSet doesn't work

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I need to put Set in SharedPreference, but I have a problem.

when I click button, I will get Set from SharedPreference and add data to Set then put back SharedPreference, but when I destroy project and open it again, the sharedPreference only get one string in Set

```
SharedPreferences s = getSharedPreferences("db", 0);
Log.i("chauster", "1.set = "+s.getStringSet("set", new HashSet<String>()));

Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        SharedPreferences ss = getSharedPreferences("db", 0);
        Set<String> hs = ss.getStringSet("set", new HashSet<String>());
        hs.add(String.valueOf(hs.size()+1));
        Editor edit = ss.edit();
        edit.putStringSet("set", hs);
        edit.commit();
        SharedPreferences sss = getSharedPreferences("db", 0);
        Log.i("chauster", "2.set = "+sss.getStringSet("set",
                new HashSet<String>()));
    }
});
```

when I install project first, and I click button 4 times, the logcat print it

```
1.set = []
2.set = [1]
2.set = [2, 1]
2.set = [3, 2, 1]
2.set = [3, 2, 1, 4]
```

it's look like success to put string in sharedPreference Set, but when I destroy app and open it again, the logcat print it

```
1.set = [1]
```

it means only one string in Set from sharedPreference, I don't know what's happened?
Please help me. thanks~

Comment: Maybe you should accept my answer as the accepted one is wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use edit.clear()  before putStringSet

```
SharedPreferences ss = getSharedPreferences("db", 0);
Set<String> hs = ss.getStringSet("set", new HashSet<String>());
hs.add(String.valueOf(hs.size()+1));
Editor edit = ss.edit();
edit.clear();
edit.putStringSet("set", hs);
edit.commit();
```

Comment: why doesn't it work without clear... is same key have a problem?

Comment: This is not a solution... clear() deletes all preferences!

Comment: This would clear _all_ preferences, remove by key instead - `edit.remove('set')`.  But this is avoided by creating a new set from the one returned from pref, like so `Set<String> new = new HashSet<>(ss.getStringSet('set', new HashSet<String>()));`

Comment: does not work...

Answer (score 64):

You fell to the usual trap of editing the value you got from getStringSet(). This is forbidden [in the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getStringSet%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29)

You should :

```
SharedPreferences ss = getSharedPreferences("db", 0);
Set<String> hs = ss.getStringSet("set", new HashSet<String>());
Set<String> in = new HashSet<String>(hs);
in.add(String.valueOf(hs.size()+1));
ss.edit().putStringSet("set", in).commit(); // brevity
// SharedPreferences sss = getSharedPreferences("db", 0); // not needed
Log.i("chauster", "2.set = "+ ss.getStringSet("set", new HashSet<String>()));
```

For a half baked explanation see : [Misbehavior when trying to store a string set using SharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034803/misbehavior-when-trying-to-store-a-string-set-using-sharedpreferences/14034804#14034804)

Comment: Thank you for posting this with a reference to the explanation!

Comment: Poor SDK design. The implementation should return an immutable set if that's a requirement (`Collections.unmodifiableSet()`).

Comment: I had posted an issue back then @Jeffrey - can't find it now

Comment: This is the correct answer. I wasted hours hunting down the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`Remove` the key for `HashSet` in `SharedPreferences`, `commit` then add new value.

```
SharedPreferences ss;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_third);
    ss = getSharedPreferences("db", 0);
    fun();
}

void fun() {
    Log.i("chauster", "1.set = "+ss.getStringSet("set", new HashSet<String>()));

    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Set<String> hs = ss.getStringSet("set", new HashSet<String>());
            hs.add(String.valueOf(hs.size()+1));
            Log.i(TAG, "list: " + hs.toString());
            Editor edit = ss.edit();
            edit.remove("set");
            edit.commit();
            edit.putStringSet("set", hs);
            Log.i(TAG, "saved: " + edit.commit());

            Log.i("chauster", "2.set = "+ss.getStringSet("set", new HashSet<String>()));
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Folks, I'm keeping it here for historical reasons. Do not use this approach! (What use is it? It shows how bad code appears: the API behaves counter-intuitively, there is a gotcha, a developer tries to work-around the gotcha. Bad code appears. Later, the gotcha gets officially documented, and a different workaround is suggested, but the bad code gets shared.)

---

Try to store SharedPreferences to a static variable instead of invoking getSharedPreferences each time. This sounds terrible, but this worked for me once.

```
public class Prefs {
    // this singleton is a workaround for an Android bug:
    // two SharedPreferences objects do not see changes in each other.
    private static SharedPreferences theSingletone;
    public static SharedPreferences get(Activity from) {
        //PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
        if (theSingletone == null) {
            theSingletone = from.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        }
        return theSingletone;
    }
}
```