# Show error when using method with older Api

Tags: android, annotations, android-library

I'm trying to make a library in which I want a method to be used only if it is above a certain API level.

I want the type of error shown here under `putStringSet()` method

[image]

I have used `@TargetApi` annotation but no success. Developer is still able to use that method without error.

Can you also tell what this type of error is called (in `putStringSet()` method)

Comment: have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21401062/5110595)

Comment: Are you asking for android lint tools. https://android.jlelse.eu/writing-custom-lint-rules-and-integrating-them-with-android-studio-inspections-or-carefulnow-c54d72f00d30

Comment: Read the link above and https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint.html this one too to create custom lint rules for your project. :)

Comment: @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) works fine too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for:

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
```

This means that only apps with min sdk of 5.0 (21?) and higher can call this. Others won't be able this method (due to a compile error), so creating and storing an error for that (specially in preferences, of all places) will be pointless.